# Angular 4.1.3 routing could not resolve child module from parent module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Thank you ahead of time for any help!!!!

Hello, As the title says. I'm getting the following error.... I'm trying to do a bunch of research and figure it out, but nothing I do seems to work. Here are some important files, does anyone have experience with this issue or see the problem? (Also the error is coming from ng serve and ng build but with ng serve it fails first then automatically rebuilds and works perfectly. So it does work with ng serve but since the first is a fail I can't build it (which obviously is the main problem)

```
ERROR in Could not resolve "patient.module" from "d:/Downloads/AngularApp/AngularApp/src/app/app.module.ts".
```

app.routing.ts

```
const patientRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'patient',
        loadChildren: 'app/patient/patient.module.ts#PatientModule',
    }
];

const nurseRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'nurse',
        loadChildren: 'app/nurse/nurse.module.ts#NurseModule',
    }
];


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'auth',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        component: AutenticationComponent
    },
    ...patientRoutes,
    ...nurseRoutes
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

patient.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }                 from '@angular/common';
import { patientRouting }               from './patient.routing';

import { PatientDashboardComponent }    from './dashboard/patient-dashboard.component';


@NgModule({
              imports:      [
                  CommonModule,
                  patientRouting
              ],
              declarations: [
                  PatientDashboardComponent
              ]
          })
export class PatientModule { }
```

patient.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }          from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }         from '@angular/router';

import { PatientComponent }             from './patient.component';
import { PatientDashboardComponent }    from './dashboard/patient-dashboard.component';
import { PatientVideoComponent }             from './video/video-chat.component';

const patientRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'patient',
        component: PatientComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: PatientVideoComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: PatientDashboardComponent,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const patientRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(patientRoutes);
```

angularcli.json

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found something on this and this seems to work. They changed their routing structure so instead of saying app/patient just go directly to using ./patient for example.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3623

Answer (score 0):

app/dir1/dir2/...

(assuming the routes module is configured inside app directory) to
./dir1/dir2/...

Can solve this problem:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'customers',
    loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'

  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
  },
  {
    path:'contacts',
    loadChildren:'./contacts/contacts.module#ContactsModule'
  },
  { 
    path:'',
    redirectTo:'',
    pathMatch:'full'
  }  
];
```